# What happens if I choose Azure container registry as artifact sources in azure devops release pipeline?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-aks

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/artifacts?view=azure-devops#container) states "By default, builds are downloaded to the agent. You can configure an option in the stage to skip the download of artifacts." Does that mean that the agents will pull the container?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What happens if I choose Azure container registry as artifact sources in azure devops release pipeline?

I agree with you.

According to the document [Azure Container Registry, Docker, Kubernetes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/artifacts?view=azure-devops#dockersource):

> When deploying containerized apps, the container image is first pushed
>   to a container registry. After the push is complete, **the container
>   image can be deployed to the Web App for Containers service or a
>   Docker/Kubernetes cluster**. You must create a service connection with
>   credentials to connect to your service to deploy images located there,
>   or to Azure.

So, when we set the ACR as artifact source, it will pull the container image. And we do not to download the Artifact again. we could use following scripts to skip it:

```
- job: Deploy
  pool:
    vmImage: 'ubuntu-16.04'
  steps:
  - checkout: none #skip checking out the default repository resource
```

Hope this helps.